# AngularJs setDirty in Controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I'm trying to set some fields to dirty after a specific button is clicked.

template

```
<div class="col-md-4">                          
    <label class="radio radio--inline">
      <input type="radio" class="radio__control" name="radio_Role"ng-model="Form.RoleCheck" value="1" required> 
      <span class="radio__label">
         Whatever
      </span> 
    </label>
</div>

<button id="gotoPersonendatenVn" ng-click="dirty()" type="button">
        Dirty
</button>
```

app.js

```
$scope.dirty = function(){
    $scope.Form.RoleCheck.$setDirty();
}
```

I've tried different things but i always get "TypeError: $scope.Form.RoleCheck is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check where you try to add `$setDirty`, you try add it to ngModel, not to the `name="radio_Role"`

And where is yours form

```
<form name="Form">

 <input type="radio" class="radio__control" name="radio_Role" ng-model="modelName" value="1" required>
```

if you want set input as dirty

$scope.Form.radio_Role = false;

Comment: $scope.radio_Role.$setDirty(); still getiing the same error

Comment: I got a form wrapped around. TypeError: $scope.Form.radio_Role is undefined

Comment: $scope.Form.radio_Role = false;